# Internationalization support in Avalonia

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, avaloniaui

Is there a way to reference language-dependent resources like text, graphics, etc. from XAML in Avalonia? Right now my solution is to provide a special I18N object with DataContext then access resources through indexer. Is there a better way?

Comment: It would be great to have NGetText of WPF within Avalonia, as it is using the standard .po files with all its support tools, e.g. POEdit.